# How can I fix this HREF issue

Tags: php, html

I am struggling with an issue which I need a little bit of help with, basically I have created a search bar and when the results come up I only want the 'Session 1' or 'Session 2' to be href'd. Not the whole thing. A photo below:

[img http://gyazo.com/eb677171c15b075f1fb4137d28227b3a.png](http://gyazo.com/eb677171c15b075f1fb4137d28227b3a.png)

I would just like the Sessions to be hrefed but the paragraphs just.

My code below:

```
echo "<p><a href='../pages/session.php</a>".$results['1']."'><h3>".$results['title']."</h3>".$results['text']."</‌​p>";
```

Linking to my DB

Note that is not all of my code just where I believe the issue lies.

Comment: Your opening `a` tag is missing a bracket.

Comment: How do you want your link address (href) to look like?

Comment: @Daniel Just so that a user can click it and redirect to the 'Session' page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed `</a>` slightly wrong. The correct solution would be like this:

```
echo "<p><a href='../pages/session.php'>{$results['1']}</a><h3>{$results['title']}</h3>{$results['text']}</‌​p>";
```

If you use double quotes, you do not need to concatenate variables into your string, they are also validate within the string.

---

UPDATE

To display only the headlines as links try this:

```
echo "<a href='../pages/session.php'><h3>{$results['title']}</h3></a><p>{$results['text']}</‌​p>";
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in D:\xampp\htdocs\wd1_osmanovic_0100348514\pages\search.php on line 107

Comment: sorry, i missed sorrounding those variables with braces. Please try the updated solution.

Comment: Hi there Daniel, thanks for your help but unfortunately it isn't working :(

Comment: Okay, How exactly do you want this paragraph to look like? Is it just a styling issue?

Comment: Basically right now I am seeing this..  http://gyazo.com/daeacfd10f7e3dd37f54b1a4681dcc1a *Note the Session 1 at the top right.. I would like Session 1 and Session 2 to be both clickable but the text to just be text basically non clickable

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a bracket in ur `a` tag.It is like `<a href='whatever'>blah</a>`

Comment: The whole thing now has become unhrefed :/

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to href $results['1']? Here you go.

```
echo "<p><a href='../pages/session.php'>".$results['1']."</a><h3>".$results['title']."</h3>".$results['text']."</‌​p>";
```

Comment: I would like Session names to be hrefed the code above you gave me made everything unhreffed. If that made sense?

Comment: You may want to include your session names between tag <a href='..'>SESSION NAMES</a>